# Gaps in Mosaic Dataset made in ArcMap 10.0 SP5

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, export, mosaic

I have created a mosaic dataset and then filled it with a set of georeferenced ECW images using the "Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset" tool. The problem is that when I export the map to PDF at a large scale (1/1000) everything seems to be fine but when I export the map to PDF at a smaller scale (1/5000) small rectangular gaps appear like in the following example. [image: image_holes] 
The weird thing is that  that in both maps (large scale and small scale) the printed area of both pages are the same size.

At the following photo you can view the settings that I used with the Add Rasters to Mosaic Dataset tool. I tried once more using maximimum levels set to 3 instead to null but without success. While exporting I use the default settings.
[image: image_holes]

Has this problem happened to anybody else?

Comment: ArcGIS 10.0 had a number of service packs before it was placed in "mature" status, and was "retired" three months ago. Please edit the question to indicate the service pack you have applied (SP5 was the last one) and what follow-on patches were applied (there were dozens).  If you don't have the terminal release, that would be a good first effort. Please use the image embedding function of SE, since external links can fail over time.

Comment: I have added that it is SP5 and the image embedding function but how can I find what follow-on-patches? I I don't have the most recent ones, are they free or do I have to buy them extra?

Comment: Service packs and patches are always free, and available from support.esri.com